# How to locate an object in an image?

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, aforge, emgucv

I have a black and white image containing objects from a set. I'd like to be able to locate these objects. I'm almost sure that the objects in the image are the same size and almost exactly the same shape as the samples in my set.

One way of doing this is to move the objects in my set one by one over the image until I get a reasonable match between the pixels in my image and the pixels in the sample object. I can write my own code for this but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel. Is there anything in AForge or EMGU/OpenCV that does this already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use openCV's Match template function. This function takes a template "your set of objects" and compares them with the image in which you think the same objects are located.

[Link to the opencv doc about matchtemplate](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/object_detection.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have [matchTemplate](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html?highlight=matchtemplate#matchtemplate) in openCV that do basically what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

You should use matching, take this sample code:

```
// Object_Matching_surf.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>
using namespace cv;
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include"cv.h"
#include"highgui.h"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int object_detection(Mat, Mat, char*);
Mat rotateImage(const Mat&, double);
int main()
{
    char inputImgName[50];
    char tmplateName[50];
    char outputImgName[50];

    for (int i=1; i<10; i++)
    {
        sprintf(inputImgName, "%s%d%s","C:/Matches1/img",i,".png");
        sprintf(tmplateName, "%s%d%s","C:/Matches1/gripper",i,".png");
        sprintf(outputImgName, "%s%d%s","C:/Matches1/matches_img",i,".png");


    Mat templateImage = imread(tmplateName);//, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );

    Mat inputImage = imread(inputImgName);//, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
    char * outPutImage = outputImgName;


    object_detection (templateImage, inputImage, outPutImage);

    }


    //Resize the template image
    /*Mat newTemlate;
    resize(templateImage,newTemlate, Size(100,100));*/

    //Rotate the template
    /*Mat rotatedTemplate  = rotateImage(templateImage, 90.0);
    imwrite("C:/Matches0/rotated.jpg" ,rotatedTemplate);*/

    return 0;
}

int object_detection(Mat templateImage, Mat inputImage, char* outPutImage)
{
    //Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector
    int minHessian = 500;

    SiftFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );
    std::vector<KeyPoint> kp_object;

    detector.detect( templateImage, kp_object );

    //Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
    SiftDescriptorExtractor extractor;
    Mat des_object;

    extractor.compute( templateImage, kp_object, des_object );

    FlannBasedMatcher matcher;

    std::vector<Point2f> obj_corners(4);

    //Get the corners from the object
    obj_corners[0] = cvPoint(0,0);
    obj_corners[1] = cvPoint( templateImage.cols, 0 );
    obj_corners[2] = cvPoint( templateImage.cols, templateImage.rows );
    obj_corners[3] = cvPoint( 0, templateImage.rows );

        Mat des_image, img_matches;
        std::vector<KeyPoint> kp_image;
        std::vector<vector<DMatch > > matches;
        std::vector<DMatch > good_matches;
        std::vector<Point2f> obj;
        std::vector<Point2f> scene;
        std::vector<Point2f> scene_corners(4);
        Mat H;

        detector.detect( inputImage, kp_image );
        extractor.compute( inputImage, kp_image, des_image );

        matcher.knnMatch(des_object, des_image, matches, 2);

        for(int i = 0; i < min(des_image.rows-1,(int) matches.size()); i++) //THIS LOOP IS SENSITIVE TO SEGFAULTS
        {
            if((matches[i][0].distance < 0.6*(matches[i][1].distance)) && ((int) matches[i].size()<=2 && (int) matches[i].size()>0))
            {
                good_matches.push_back(matches[i][0]);
            }
        }

        //Draw only "good" matches
        drawMatches( templateImage, kp_object, inputImage, kp_image, good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1), vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );

        if (good_matches.size() >= 4)
        {
            for( int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++ )
            {
                //Get the keypoints from the good matches
                obj.push_back( kp_object[ good_matches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
                scene.push_back( kp_image[ good_matches[i].trainIdx ].pt );
            }

            H = findHomography( obj, scene, CV_RANSAC );

            perspectiveTransform( obj_corners, scene_corners, H);

            //Draw lines between the corners (the mapped object in the scene image )
            line( img_matches, scene_corners[0] + Point2f( templateImage.cols, 0), scene_corners[1] + Point2f( templateImage.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4 );
            line( img_matches, scene_corners[1] + Point2f( templateImage.cols, 0), scene_corners[2] + Point2f( templateImage.cols, 0), Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
            line( img_matches, scene_corners[2] + Point2f( templateImage.cols, 0), scene_corners[3] + Point2f( templateImage.cols, 0), Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
            line( img_matches, scene_corners[3] + Point2f( templateImage.cols, 0), scene_corners[0] + Point2f( templateImage.cols, 0), Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
        }

        //Computing the center
        Point2f p1 = scene_corners[0] + Point2f( templateImage.cols, 0);
        Point2f p2 = scene_corners[1] + Point2f( templateImage.cols, 0);
        Point2f p3 = scene_corners[2] + Point2f( templateImage.cols, 0);
        Point2f p4 = scene_corners[3] + Point2f( templateImage.cols, 0);
        Point2f center = (p3*0.5+p1*0.5);

        char p1text[20];
        sprintf(p1text, "(%d,%d)",(int)p1.x, (int)p1.y );
        putText(img_matches, p1text, p1, FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.3, cvScalar(255, 255, 255, 0));

        char p2text[20];
        sprintf(p2text, "(%d,%d)",(int)p2.x, (int)p2.y );
        putText(img_matches, p2text, p2, FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.3, cvScalar(255, 255, 255, 0));

        char p3text[20];
        sprintf(p3text, "(%d,%d)",(int)p3.x, (int)p3.y );
        putText(img_matches, p3text, p3, FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.3, cvScalar(255, 255, 255, 0));

        char p4text[20];
        sprintf(p4text, "(%d,%d)",(int)p4.x, (int)p4.y );
        putText(img_matches, p4text, p4, FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.3, cvScalar(255, 255, 255, 0));

        char centertext[20];
        sprintf(centertext, "(%d,%d)",(int)center.x, (int)center.y );
        putText(img_matches, centertext, center, FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.3, cvScalar(255, 0, 0, 250));

        system("pause");

        /* Save the image of matches */
        imwrite(outPutImage, img_matches);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thats probably because it a bit of a large solution for a simple question. There are simpeler and more efficient ways to do this. (btw, it was not me who -1 nd you).

Comment: I have spent so much time in that subject, that's why this could be helpful, but anyway the size of the answer should not be a criterion :))

Comment: That is one thing that i agree on, The effectiveness on the other hand is very important. Besides, i have spend my days using openCV aswell. :) Now, lets stop debatting ;)

Comment: @HoussemBdr -1 because it's a huge block of copy-paste code with no effort to explain how it answers the question, especially because it's C++ answering a C# question.  Suggest to improve the answer by editing to summarize the key tools in OpenCV that enable the above program - the algorithm in its entirety is superfluous, particularly because it is a specific implementation answering a general question.

Comment: I supposed that he made enough effort to understand it and make just export from c++ to c#, no problem anyway:)